# Docker & Nginx: jwilder/nginx doesn't take special chars in VIRTUAL_HOST env var

Tags: url, docker, nginx, special-characters

I've tried to set up my website with Docker and I use jwilder/nginx image as a reverse proxy.

I have two domains that redirects to my server : **ctrfcn.com** and **ctrfçn.com**

When I set the VIRTUAL_HOST env variable of my container to **ctrfcn.com**, Nginx properly makes the redirection. But when I use my domain with a **ç** in it, its just giving me a 503 response.

Does anyone know how to handle these new authorized charcaters in URLs ?

Cheers.

Comment: Get into the nginx proxy container and see what is the generated config using `nginx -T` and see if it has any errors